Pie chart using the values of one variable when repeated multiple times r
I want to plot a pie chart with slices of values given by a column, these values are repeated multiple time.
df <- data.frame(answer_type_count= rep(c("6","46", "3"),2),
      answer_type= rep(c("correct", "wrong","no answer"),2))

Basically I would like a slice of 46, one of 6 and another one of 3 (out of a total of 55)...possibly even adding percentage and number.
I tried:
library(ggplot)
bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=answer_type_count, fill=answer_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
bp


I am sure it is very easy, but I cannot find the right question on this website despite a long research

Most of your problems are actually data manipulation issues. Try the following where I convert your answer_type_count column to a numeric and then calculate a percentage for labelling.
 df <- df %>% distinct() %>% # remove duplicate data rows
  mutate(answer_type_count = as.numeric(answer_type_count),
    percent = round(answer_type_count/sum(answer_type_count)*100,0),
    answer_type = as.factor(answer_type));df


bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=answer_type_count, fill=answer_type))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
# Create percent labels. 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(percent, "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()); bp # Remove axis text



thank you so much for your time and advice but would you know a solution that does not involve removing the duplicated data rows? I would not be able to do it in my actual dataset

It is difficult to understand why you would want it that way if the data are truly identical, so I'm assuming there are other variables not accounted for in the example data you provided. In that case you can simply remove the call to distinct(), but you won't get different colors unless you have a unique identifier for each row that you can use as the fill.

If you can provide more context maybe I can help, but in the question you state that you only want to plot out of a total of 55. Let me know if you can clear up exactly what you mean. It may help to provide dput(mydata).

Thanks again, if I remove the call to 'distinct()' the total is 110 and not 55 (which is my initial difficulty!)t. What is 'dput(mydata)'?

Correct, the function dplyr::distict() will remove any rows in your data which are exact duplicates, which is why it seems to make sense from your example to use it and the resulting df totals to 55. If you have other variables you could create a custom dataframe for plotting. Something like df_plot <- df %>% dplyr::select(answer_type_count,answer_type).  If you enter dput(mydata) into the console it returns all the necessary info for others to recreate your data exactly simply by pasting the output and saving to an object. Obviously replace "mydata" with your data name dput(df)

Perhaps summarise the data by "answer_type" first and then plot (this doesn't call distinct):
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

summarise(df, n=sum(answer_type_count), N=sum(n), .by=answer_type) |>
  mutate(N=sum(N), pct=n/sum(n), Answer=fct_reorder(answer_type, -n)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=n, fill=Answer)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(pct)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=3) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.5, y = N, 
            label = paste('Total =', N)), size = 4, vjust = -0.5)


